# Playwright auto-scroll to bottom of infinite-scroll page

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, playwright

I am trying to automate the scraping of a site with "infinite scroll" with Python and Playwright.

The issue is that Playwright doesn't include, as of yet, a scroll functionnality let alone an infinite auto-scroll functionnality.

From what I found on the net and my personnal testing, I can automate an infinite or finite scroll using the `page.evaluate()` function and some Javascript code.

For example, this works:

```
for i in range(20):
    page.evaluate('var div = document.getElementsByClassName("comment-container")[0];div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight')
    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
```

The problem with this approach is that it will either work by specifying a number of scrolls or by telling it to keep going forever with a `while True` loop.

I need to find a way to tell it to keep scrolling until the final content loads.

This is the Javascript that I am currently trying in `page.evaluate()`:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);
    scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
    console.log('fail')
}, 1000);
var anotherID = setInterval(function() {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }}, 1000)
```

This does not work either in my firefox browser or in the Playwright firefox browser. It returns immediately and doesn't execute the code in intervals.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me how I can, using Playwright, create an auto-scroll function that will detect and stop when it reaches the bottom of a dynamically loading webpage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new Playwright version has a scroll function. it's called [`mouse.wheel(x, y)`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-mouse#mouse-wheel). In the below code, we'll be attempting to scroll through youtube.com which has an "infinite scroll":

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
import time


def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()

    # Open new page
    page = context.new_page()

    page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/')

    # page.mouse.wheel(horizontally, vertically(positive is 
    # scrolling down, negative is scrolling up)
    for i in range(5): #make the range as long as needed
        page.mouse.wheel(0, 15000)
        time.sleep(2)
        
    
    time.sleep(15)
    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Comment: This removes the need to mix JS with Python. Just for that reason it is a better answer in my opinion. Therefore I am accepting it.
To make it a perfect answer to my question one would need to reindent correctly the code and point out a way to do an infinite scroll and stop when the scrolling is done. ;)

Comment: It not works. Always scroll one screen, and is very slow.

Answer (score 17):

So I found a working solution.

What I did was to combine Javascript with python Playwright code.

I start the setInterval with a timer of 200ms to scroll down on the page with `page.evaluate()` and then I follow it up with a python loop that checks every second whether the total height of the page (scroll included) has changed. If it changes it continues to scroll and if it hasn't changed than the scroll is over.
This is what it looks like:

```
page.evaluate(
    """
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);
        scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
    }, 200);

    """
)
prev_height = None
while True:
    curr_height = page.evaluate('(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY)')
    if not prev_height:
        prev_height = curr_height
        time.sleep(1)
    elif prev_height == curr_height:
        page.evaluate('clearInterval(intervalID)')
        break
    else:
        prev_height = curr_height
        time.sleep(1)
```

### EDIT

See the below answer using the new mouse.wheel(x, y) feature for an up to date way to scroll using playwright. Combine my answer with his to lessen the need to use JS.

Comment: Nice! This can also be adapted to slowly scroll the page to the end with e.g. `scrollTop += 200` instead of just assigning `scrollHeight`.

Comment: worked instantly. Great solution, for js-only

Answer (score 9):

The other solutions were a tad bit verbose and "overkill" for me and this is what worked for me.

Here's a two liner that took me a few migraines to come around to :)

**Note:** you are going to have to *put in your own selector*. This is just an example...

```
    while page.locator("span",has_text="End of results").is_visible() is False:
        page.mouse.wheel(0,100)
        #page.keyboard.down(PageDown) also works
```

Literally just keep scrolling until some sort of unique selector is present. In this case a span tag with the string "End of results" (for the context of my use case) popped up when you scroll to the bottom.

I trust you can translate this logic for you own usage..

Answer (score 5):

the playwright has the `page.keyboard.down('End')` command, it will scroll to the end of the page.

Comment: "End" will not scroll to the bottom of an infinite scroll page.

Comment: Of course it won't, you just need to create a button detection and press it (if it has a 'load more' option), or simply detect the spinner (like on YouTube). As long as it's on the screen, you haven't reached the end. This will vary from site to site (so there's no way to provide a generic example).

Answer (score 0):

So I was faced with a similar issue, but it was a specific element that has scroll and not the page itself, what I found out is if you click on the element in question and apply focus to it, page.mouse.wheel will scroll that specific element. (in my case my element was a tbody)

```
async scrollIntoView (locator : Locator) {
        let i = 0;
        while(await locator.isHidden()) {
            await this.page.locator('your locator goes here').click();
            await this.page.mouse.wheel(0, 300);
            i++;
            if (await locator.isVisible()) { return; }
            else if (i >= 5) { return; }
        }
    }
```

you can remove the incremental guard with `i` i just have it there to avoid any infinite loops.

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me:

```py
prev_page_height = page.evaluate("$(document).height()") 
print(f'Initial page height {prev_page_height}')

# scroll down
while True:
    page.evaluate("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)   # giving some time to load the page
            
    cur_page_height = page.evaluate("$(document).height()")
    print(f'Current page height {cur_page_height}')
            
    if cur_page_height > prev_page_height:
        prev_page_height = cur_page_height
    elif cur_page_height == prev_page_height:
        break
```

Comment: Don't think you need to resort to jQuery just to get the current document height.

Answer (score -3):

This topic old, but new to me. I have been using the playwright wheel scroll but for me it takes control/focus on the mouse.

So if I happen to be typing (which i usually am) and it scrolls, my beautiful words go into the void to never be seen again.

I am going to go ahead and try out the js solution posted above and see if that gets me around the mouse/focus issue.

Comment: I have to downvote cuz I don\` think this is an answer

Comment: It is additional information about the function being discussed (platwright mouse wheel), so no, I don't think you 'had' to vote it down.