# Playwright cant click element in table with scrollbar

Tags: playwright

I'm using Playwright for the first time. I have a table with many columns so there is a horizontal scrollbar. The last column has an "actions" button. It can't seem to be clicked (or I guess located) because it's not visible, I guess. I know this because if I run in debug mode and then scroll myself, the rest of the test completes. I tried `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` and that does nothing. Is there anyway I can scroll the table myself or is there some better approach?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the site and a [mcve] of your code. Every site has unique behavior and selectors, so there's no generic/silver bullet way to achieve this. Odds are, if someone just guessed, it wouldn't work for you, resulting in frustration and wasted time for all concerned.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73378990/10050775