# Is there a quick way to check if iframe exists on page with Playwright and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

So I am scraping a site that has a random popup via an iframe sporadically appear as you scroll down the page. On the iframe there is a button to get rid of it. However, it's hard to be certain when it will appear.
I can get round this by just having it try and find the iframe every time it tries to scroll down the page

```
try:
    page.frame_locator('#aframe').locator('button:has-text("click me")').click()
except:
    continue
```

This works. But it's *super* slow because it waits for 30 seconds to try and find the iframe each time. I tried just lowering the timeout, but this doesn't seem to be an option for a frame locator? Is there a way to either: (a) lower the timeout for this operation, or (b) manually stop the script for two seconds and then do an immediate check. Something like:

```
time.sleep(2)
if *check for iframe* == False:
    continue
else:
    *click on button*
```

Comment: I think you have to use page.on("frameAttached"), Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267112/playwright-intercept-popup-iframe-windows/74267634#74267634

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to quickly find out if an element exists in a page or not using Playwright Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70770526/how-to-quickly-find-out-if-an-element-exists-in-a-page-or-not-using-playwright-p). The fact that it's in an iframe shouldn't impact the solution (`.query_selector()` instead of `.locator()`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having timeout to wait for iframe to appear, Try using [waitFor()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-wait-for), It will wait until the iframe loaded.

```
    const clickme = page.frame_locator('#aframe').locator('button:has-text("click me")');
    await clickme.waitFor();
    await clickme.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this is that OP wants to scroll and take actions between each check, so this would be too slow even if converted to Python. It's pretty much what they're already attempting. OP wants an instantaneous check, not a wait, which is that locators do.